# intermittent java.lang.LinkageError in Eclipse RCP - Equinox

Tags: equinox

I'm developing a project with Equinox execution environment and I'm using the cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution CXF bundle. I'm running my tests within Eclipse RCP (galileo). When I started the program for the first time with the newly added CXF bundle everything worked fine. But at the second try I got a java.lang.LinkageError in cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution bundle. I added some ad hoc "uses" directives, and the problem diappeared. But at the subsequent start the LinkageError was there again! So I modify again (with touch manifest.mf !!!) the manifest and the program started correctly. 
The point is that Eclipse is able to correctly start the bundles if and only if I "touch" the manifest file of cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution.
Does anyone have never experienced a similar issue?

Thank you very much,
matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Whom It May Concern: I completely removed and recreated from scratch the eclipse workspace and I upgraded the cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution to a newly available version (I was using v 1.1 and I upgraded to v 1.2). The problem disappeared.